When to use a definite article?
In Menschen A1.1, there are the following sentences:

Ich liebe die Natur.
Ich liebe Musik.

Why is there an article with Natur and not with Musik? Wouldn't it be correct to say Ich liebe Natur (I like Nature) without an article?

In general, the use of definite articles in German vs. English is usually the same. But the rules in both languages are quite complex and detailed. For example you say "I love nature," but "I love the internet." Listing all the cases where English and German differ on this would not be practical here. So I think answers will have to be limited to the specific examples in the question, namely "lieben" with either "Natur" or "Musik".

Related question

I suspect your native language is a Slavic one so you aren't used to definiteness: it's a bit vague and not governed by hard grammatical rules but rather by the viewpoint and typical ways to express things. That's why English and German, two closely related languages (both West Germanic) agree in the majority of cases on this but in some corner cases as this one they differ.
In English, it's both I love nature. and I love music. because English speakers assign the same properties to both things: they are concepts —things that exist in your mind— and as such, cannot be definite.
But German speakers disagree strongly in case of nature. Nature isn't a concept but a very real thing and as such, it has to be definite.
For music, you can actually use both in German. If you wrote Ich liebe die Musik it would either be a particular music (demonstrative) or you want to express the same way as with die Natur that music isn't just in your mind but a very real thing to you. For example if you are a musician yourself you would rather use Ich liebe die Musik than Ich liebe Musik.
